# Print lines around position in the file

Tags: bash, file, awk, sed

I'm importing a big csv (5gb) file to the BiqQuery and I had information about an error in the file and its position — specified as a byte offset from the start of the file (for example, 134683757). I'd like to look at lines around this error position.

Some example lines of the file:

```
field1, field2, field3
abc, bcd, efg
...
dge, hfr, kdf,
dgj, "a""a", fbd # in this line is an invalid csv element and I get error, let's say on the position 134683757 
skd, frd, lqw
...
asd, fij, fle
```

I need some command to show lines around error like

```
dge, hfr, kdf,
dgj, "a""a", fbd 
skd, frd, lqw
```

I tried `sed` and `awk` but I didn't find any simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

It was definitely not clear from the original version of the question that you only got a byte offset from the start of the file.

You need to get a better position from the software generating the error; the developer was lazy in reporting an unusable number.  It is reasonable to request a line number (and preferably offset within the line), rather than (or as well as) the byte offset from the start.

Assuming that the number is a byte position in the file, that gets tricky. Most Unix utilities work with lines (of variable length).  I'd be tempted to write some C code to do the job, but that might be beyond you (and no shame in that).

Failing that, your best is likely the `dd` command. If the number reported is `134683757`, then I'd guess that your lines are probably not more than 1 KiB each (adjust numbers if they're bigger, or smaller), and then use:

```
 dd if=big.csv of=extract.csv bs=1 skip=$((134683757 - 3 * 1024)) count=6144
 echo >> extract.csv
```

You'd then look at extract.csv. The raw `dd` output probably won't have a newline at the end of the last line (the `echo >>extract.csv` fixes that). The output will probably start part way through a record and end part way through another record. However, you're likely to have the relevant information, as well as some irrelevant information. As I said, adjust the numbers to suit your exact situation.

The trickiest part is identifying exactly where the byte offset is in the file you get.  With custom C code, that can be provided easily (more easily).  With the output from `dd`, you have to do the calculation yourself.

```
awk -v offset=$((134683757 - 3 * 1024)) '
    { printf "%9d: %s\n", offset, $0; offset += length($0) + 1 }
    ' extract.cvs
```

That takes the starting offset from the `dd` command, and prefixes the (remnants of) the first line with that number and the data; it then adds the length to the offset plus one for the newline that wasn't counted, and continues to the end of the file.  That gives you the start offset for each line in the extracted data.  You can see where your actual start was by looking at the offsets — you should be able to identify which record that was.

You could use a variant of this Awk script that reads the whole file line by line, and tracks the offset (as well as the line numbers) and prints the data when it gets to the vicinity of where you have the problem.

In times long past, I had to deal with data from 1/2 inch mag tapes (those big circular tapes you see in old movies) where the files generated on a mainframe seemed sanely formatted for the first few tens of megabytes, but then the format changed to some alternative format for a few megabytes, and then reverted to the original format once more. I never did find out why; I just learned how to deal with it.  Trial and error!